# Using Dart as a DSL

Tags: dart

I am trying to use Dart to tersely define entities in an application, following the idiom of code = configuration. Since I will be defining many entities, I'd like to keep the code as trim and concise and readable as possible.

In an effort to keep boilerplate as close to 0 lines as possible, I recently wrote some code like this:

```dart
// man.dart
part of entity_component_framework;

var _man = entity('man', (entityBuilder) {
  entityBuilder.add([TopHat, CrookedTeeth]);
})

// test.dart
part of entity_component_framework;
var man = EntityBuilder.entities['man']; // null, since _man wasn't ever accessed.
```

The `entity` method associates the entityBuilder passed into the function with a name ('man' in this case). `var _man` exists because only variable assignments can be top-level in Dart. This seems to be the most concise way possible to use Dart as a DSL.

One thing I wasn't counting on, though, is lazy initialization. If I never access `_man` -- and I had no intention to, since the `entity` function neatly stored all the relevant information I required in another data structure -- then the `entity` function is never run. [This is a feature, not a bug](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/JdLW-dE26Mw).

So, what's the cleanest way of using Dart as a DSL given the lazy initialization restriction?

Comment: I think you need to provide more context. It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. But in the small picture you could just make it be  (entityBuilder) => entityBuilder.add([TopHat, CrookedTeeth]); and have the add method return the thing that was added. Then you could say var man = _man;

Comment: I've edited the question. Basically, I am trying to use Dart to configure entities rather than parsing a YAML or some other configuration file. However, lazy initialization is preventing me from utilizing a more concise style.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/radicaled/8309609 -- to phrase it another way, lazy initialization prevents me from using a DSL without first having to touch the temporary variable (one I have no need of using, since I will be using the data store, 'potatoSack' in the example, directly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, as you point out, it's a feature that Dart doesn't run any code until it's told to. So if you want something to happen, you need to do it in code that runs. Some possibilities

Put your calls to entity() inside the main() function. I assume you don't want to do that, and probably that you want people to be able to add more of these in additional files without modifying the originals.

If you're willing to incur the overhead of mirrors, which is probably not that much if they're confined to this library, use them to find all the top-level variables in that library and access them. Or define them as functions or getters. But I assume that you like the property that variables are automatically one-shot. You'd want to use a MirrorsUsed annotation.

A variation on that would be to use annotations to mark the things you want to be initialized. Though this is similar in that you'd have to iterate over the annotated things, which I think would also require mirrors.

Comment: Agree, mirrors is your best bet. 

If I understand it correctly, you want to define entities declaratively, so that they are defined in a global data structure.

Dart isn't very good at that, for exactly the reason you have discovered: code isn't executed implicitly, you need to explicitly access a getter or call a method, or just access a lazily initialized field. That means that something needs to trigger your initialization code. You will need to call something somewhere (perhaps make EntityBuilder a lazily initialized object instead of a class), and use mirrors to find the declarations.

Comment: I settled with using `dart:mirrors` to iterate over private, top-level variable declarations that conformed to a specific naming scheme. 10 extra lines of code, but not that bad, all things considered, I guess.

Comment: I was disappointed when I found out that mirrors is not supported by flutter.